# npm install -Error /npm/optimist/0.3.7' - Linux Mint

Tags: linux, node.js, express, npm, linux-mint

I'm new to node and npm, I'm running npm install on Linux MINT and  the error I'm getting is this one:

> Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
>   npm ERR! node v0.10.35
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.1.17
>   **npm ERR! path /home/rolando/.npm/optimist/0.3.7**
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno 3
>
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/rolando/.npm/optimist/0.3.7'
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/rolando/.npm/optimist/0.3.7']
>   npm ERR!   errno: 3,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/home/rolando/.npm/optimist/0.3.7',
>   npm ERR!   parent: 'uglify-js' }
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

---

One thing a notice is that I have the optimist 0.6.1 on my machine (not the 0.3.7), how can I fix that?? I already run an update with curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

My node -v is 0.10.35 , the npm  is 2.1.17

Also If I  run npm cache clean then I will get following:

> Error: EACCES, unlink '/home/rolando/.npm/async/0.2.10'
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/home/rolando/.npm/async/0.2.10']
>   npm ERR!   errno: 3,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/home/rolando/.npm/async/0.2.10' }

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the contributors of npm gave me the answer on the github forum, it was something to do with the permission like you said Victor

> sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a permission problem in your folder `/home/rolando/.npm/`.  Set the permissions in your folder and try again:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/rolando/.npm/
```

Maybe you have problems in your nodejs installation. Install node with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and it should works.